# calculus 1 and binomial theorem

Tags: calculus

I started my calculus 1 studies and they may differ from the one in us,it`s kind of basics so hope you can guide me out
I need to prove for every Neutral number that:
[what need to be proven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6J9g.png)

[opened the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB9Rh.png)

[thats equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQAmd.png)

and in the forth step
[binomial theorem try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A5Z1.png)
i tried to use binomial theorem
but cant really figure out if I did it right,and even if i did whats my next step?
thanks

Comment: It's a better idea to write the math in your question for improved readability rather than posting links to images. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Also, try to use more descriptive titles instead of "calculus problem..."

Answer (score 2):

$$ \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

$$ 4^n = (1+1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} 1^{2n-k} 1^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}$$

And so of-course the sum will "hit" $\binom{2n}{n}$ at $k=n$, but we would sum more than that, because this is only a small portion of the sum:

$$ \binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{1} + \dots + \color{red}{\binom{2n}{n}} + \dots + \binom{2n}{2n} $$

Comment: I quiet understand the use of binomial theorem but with numbers,what proggersion it gives me? i left with unknown ∑k=02n(2nk) thanks

Comment: What do you mean? The expression in red is supposed to be smaller than the whole sum you see it? because it is only one small portion of it. What do you mean by "what progression it gives me" ?  It's the whole solution..